# Сравнение списков в БД и List с целью удаления лишних Pl/Sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  name  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  car   VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  rank  NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (name, car)
);
```

В Java у меня есть List - обьекты, хранящие информацию name, car, rank = null.

Необходимо написать хранимую функцию (pl/sql), реализующюю следующее:

- Если в List есть обьекты, которых нет в таблице, добавить их в таблицу.
- Если в List нет записей, которые есть в таблице, удалить их из таблицы.
- В этих операциях не учитывать поле rank (т.е. при сравнении без разницы на его значение).

Додумался только до этого:

```
DECLARE  
  type my_table_array IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;
  v_Numbers my_table_array := my_table_array();

  rec  my_table%ROWTYPE;
  idx number;
BEGIN
  v_Numbers.extend(1);
  idx := v_Numbers.count;
  rec.name := 'John';
  rec.car := 'Toyota';
  rec.rank := 5;
  v_Numbers(idx) := rec;
END;
```

Как теперь в BEGIN красиво проверить? Если нету таких записей в таблице, добавить. Причем пробежать по всем v_Numbers.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону `merge`

Comment: *Или лучше эти сравнения выполнять на стороне клиента?* Работы с массивами данных лучше выполнять на стороне сервера - он как бы под это заточен... тем более что окончательно данные должны откорректироваться именно на сервере, так зачем тянуть сперва оттуда, а потом туда? В общем, выгрузить данные из List-объектов во временную таблицу да одним запросом всё и откорректировать.

Comment: Можно передать ваш List в процедуру использую UDT, и в процедуре сделать merge

Comment: Операция merge может не только добавлять новые, но и удалять отсутствующие. причем делать это одновременно в пределах одного запроса. так что процедура одна. главное первым делом, как сказал @Akina сделать временную таблицу и загрузить данные из List в нее, потому что передать набор строк в процедуру, да так что бы с ним потом было удобно работать, по другому все равно нельзя

Comment: @Mike а передать в качестве курсора и сравнивать курсор с таблицей как-нибудь нельзя?

Comment: Если записи не совпали: либо добавляем новые, либо удаляем те, которых нет в новых. Как это определить не понятно. Склоняюсь к тому, что надо сначала удалить из таблицы те, которые отсутствуют в новом наборе. После добавить записи новые.

Comment: Для начала посмотрите что ваш драйвер работы с БД позволяет передавать. Сильно сомневаюсь что там будут какие нибудь курсоры. А если даже неким списком и передадите то про merge точно можно будет забыть, надо будет по одной записи самому перебирать, потому что ничего кроме существующих таблиц в запросе вы использовать не сможете.

Comment: в запросе выборки в merge надо сделать full outer join таблицы с новыми строками и таблицы с существующими данными. после чего в части update можно будет написать подходящее условие для delete (NULL к колонках с новыми данными). ну по крайней мере мне кажется должно сработать, надо будет попробовать, может чуть сложнее будет выглядеть, но наверняка решаемо

Comment: @Mike спасибо, подумаю. Но очень не хочется использовать новую таблицу как буфер. Если нельзя передать всесь List и сделать Insert в процедуре, полсе merge этих данных. То и Insert в буфферную таблицу придется делать по одному запросу на запись...

Comment: ну вопрос в количестве данных. они же просто в запрос могут не влезть. так то можно и в merge написать в качестве таблицы `select 'a','b' from DUAL union all select 'c','d' from DUAL ...` но сколько это займет. А insert ... ну да, конечно по одному запросу. вернее запрос то будет всего один, просто надо будет много раз сделать его execute (т.е. что бы стадия компиляции запроса была одна). Да и таблица, если она будет создана как temporary table будет практически вся в ОЗУ и запись в нее будет быстрой и без фиксации изменений в сегменте отката и redo логах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для синхронизации двух наборов данных лучше всего использовать `MERGE`. Набор с новыми данными может быть любым, каким вам будет удобно (и возможно). Я нашел [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20719708/5669174) передачи из java в oracle массива объектного типа, что удобно при использовании в процедуре. Но если с ним будут какие то проблемы, вместо него можно использовать временную таблицу (global temporary table) или передавать данные в виде текста внутри merge (в виде подзапроса вида `select 'x','y' from DUAL union select 'z','z' ...`) или в виде текста как параметра процедуры (`call my_procedure( my_rec_list( my_rec('x','y',NULL), my_rec('z','z',NULL)))` ).

Если вы примете решение передавать в виде массива то надо будет создать объектный тип записи и тип массив таких объектов:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_rec AS OBJECT(
  name  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  car   VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
  rank  NUMBER  -- Поле rank можно не включать и не передавать, если не нужно
);

CREATE TYPE my_rec_list AS TABLE OF my_rec;
```

При этом хранимая процедура, обновляющая таблицу будет выглядеть так:

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure(LIST my_rec_list) is
begin
  merge into my_table O
  using (
         select nvl(X.name,T.name) name, nvl(X.car,T.car) car, X.name as x_name
           from (select * from TABLE(LIST)) X
           full outer join my_table T on T.name=X.name and T.car=X.car
        ) N on(O.name=N.name and O.car=N.car)
 when not matched then insert(name,car) values(N.name,N.car)
 when matched then
   update set O.rank=O.rank
   delete where x_name is null;
end my_procedure;
```

Строка `update` в merge ничего не меняет в БД, так как пытается изменить колонку на саму себя, но она необходима для того, что бы в запросе можно было указать строку `delete`.

Comment: Спасибо. Я реализовал передачу по примеру из этой ссылки https://coderanch.com/t/589556/framework/Calling-Stored-Procedure-list-values. Впринципе одно и то же. Да, я создал такие же типы. Завтра пропробую ваш пример.

Comment: "an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement" - показывает на строке select * from TABLE(LIST). Нельзя просто селект сделатьл

Comment: @ks_on_v Это что то невероятное. все что тут написано это один запрос, а часть запроса ну никак into требовать не может. Что бы вызвать такую ошибку данный подзапрос `select * from TABLE` должен быть отдельным предложением в процедуре, но тогда он теряет всякий смысл. P.S. перед публикованием поста я проверял работоспособность

Comment: @ks_on_v И да, если это вы так пытаетесь отлаживаться, то имейте ввиду, процедура в Oracle не может вернуть результат select (кроме как через out параметр в виде какого нибудь композитного типа). Так что отлаживать все надо без процедуры, например непосредственно выполняя запрос

Comment: update set old_data.rank = old_data.rank; эта строчка удаляет все записи, кроме новых. Потому что в x_name лежат только новые записи из нового списка. Получается, когда до нее доходим, все записи, которые совпали в новых и старых данных стераются.

Comment: @ks_on_v Правильно. вы этого и хотели. ваша фраза: "_Если в List нет записей, которые есть в таблице, удалить их из таблицы_".

Comment: Это правильно. Но удаляются и совпадения.

Comment: @ks_on_v Этого не может быть. x_name должен быть у всех записей, которые есть во входящем списке. вы уверены, что у вас там именно FULL OUTER JOIN ?

Comment: @ks_on_v хотя даже join не может испортить этого. там же стоит X.name as x_name. А X это как раз ваша входящаяя таблица с актуальными данными и запрос физически должен выдать все записи и не выдать записи, которые совпали с существующей таблицей вообще не может ни при каких условиях.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает!!!